# How can find a proper layout from a layout list according to user entries in Js?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm to suggest the user best layout.
For this purpose, I have created the following layout list as follows:

```
function getRandomNumber(min: number, max: number) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

// Generate a random layout
function generateRandomLayout(index: number) {
  const layout = {
    name: `Layout${index + 1}`,
    options: {
      watchList: getRandomNumber(0, 5),
      instrumentDetail: getRandomNumber(0, 5),
      portfolio: getRandomNumber(1, 5),
      orders: getRandomNumber(0, 5),
      transactions: getRandomNumber(0, 5),
      chart: getRandomNumber(0, 5),
      Mazaneh: getRandomNumber(0, 5),
    },
  };
  return layout;
}
```

At generated Layout, we have options that include keys and values. the value can have a random number between [0,5].
And, 20 random layouts have been generated as follows:

```
// Generate 20 random layouts
const randomLayouts = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  const layout = generateRandomLayout(i);
  randomLayouts.push(layout);
}
```

Now, We have user scores as follows, for example:

```
const userScores= {
  watchList: 3,
  instrumentDetail: 5,
  portfolio: 2,
  transactions: 4,
  chart: 5,
  orders: 3,
  Mazaneh: 0,
};
```

Now, I'd like to find a solution to suggest user, best layout that is the most closest layout to user preferences.
Also, The options at found layout must contain closest values to user scores. And, if any field of user scores, were defined as zero. The search must be done through layouts that includes that zero field or fields.
The following link include some data for better understanding.[Codes](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/serene-meninsky-pcmf3f?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpqp305g0006356aeynqjyqh%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%252C0%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpqp305g0002356a3vv4ltjd%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpqp305g0003356a5tjf2e4q%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpqp305g0005356ah1rme433%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B56.777893639207505%252C43.222106360792495%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clpqp305g0002356a3vv4ltjd%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpqp305g0002356a3vv4ltjd%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpruefpk0002356b5bxzhhai%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A28%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A20%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A28%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A31%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252Findex.ts%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpruefpk0002356b5bxzhhai%2522%257D%252C%2522clpqp305g0005356ah1rme433%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpqp305g0004356ajxhezbiw%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpqp305g0005356ah1rme433%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clpqp305g0004356ajxhezbiw%2522%257D%252C%2522clpqp305g0003356a5tjf2e4q%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clpqp305g0003356a5tjf2e4q%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Afalse%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A0%257D)

Comment: How do you define closest? What do you want to minimize? The sum of absolute differences? The standard deviation? The variance? The sum of ratios? ... What is holding you back to  implement your desired optimisation?

Comment: I don't know the solution for this kind of problem. I am looking for possible simple and quick solution for my problem.  I have not any idea about defining closest, If, there is any criteria for this, which one is suitable and How can implement it ?

Comment: Which one is suitable, is for you to decide. It depends on what you expect as output in different scenarios where one definition of "close" may lose it when using another. It is up to you to define what you mean with "close".

Comment: My understanding from close is that , the options values in suggested layout, be enough close to user entries. for example, if user assigned Mazaneh , zero, the Mazaneh at final result must have result value.  but for non zero values, the minimum deviation suffices.

Comment: This does not clarify what close is. What is the formula you have in mind for "minimum deviation"? Like I wrote above, are you minimizing the sum of differences, the standard deviation, the variance, the ratios, ...etc. There are countless ways to define "close". This question lacks that specification.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's define what "closest" means. A possible meaning is that you have some settings and you count the similarities:

```js
function getDeviation(settings, preferences) {
   let deviation = 0;
   for (let k in settings) {
       if ((!preferences[k]) || (settings[k] !== preferences[k])) {
           deviation++
       }
   }
   return deviation;
}

let settingsMap = {
    first: {
        a: 1,
        b: 1,
        c: 1,
        d: 1
    },
    second: {
        a: 2,
        b: 2,
        c: 2,
        d: 2
    },
    third: {
        a: 3,
        b: 3,
        c: 3,
        d: 3
    },
    fourth: {
        a: 4,
        b: 4,
        c: 4,
        d: 4
    },
    fifth: {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: 3,
        d: 4
    },
};

let preferences = {
    a: 2,
    b: 2,
    d: 3
};

for (let settings in settingsMap) {
    console.log(settings + " deviation is " + getDeviation(settingsMap[settings], preferences));
}
```

But this is not necessarily the exact manner you want to operate with. You may need to weigh your differences, some settings being more important than others, also, you may want some other way to compute the deviation from some settings. For example, if we speak about background color, then color1 might be more similar to the preferred color than color2, whereas both color1 and color2 would be at least slightly different from the actual preferred color.

So, the solution I have given you above is a simplistic algorithm that you can enhance according to your needs. But the basis of the idea should be to have a formula to calculate each different setting deviation, use a weight if needed to have a sense of importance / setting and then find the setting having the minimum deviation (simple minimum search among the results) and have a mechanism to determine who "wins" in case of a tie.

EDIT

As described earlier, `getDeviation` in its most simplistic implementation computes the number of differences, but it does not compare the size of the differences. It's also very difficult to infer what and how to compute the differences.

For example, if you have a value of `2`, then one needs to figure out what is closer to it: `22` or `9` for example, so we consider these values to be texts or to be numbers. So, let's do some enhancing to see how we can elaborate on this problem:

```js
let customDeviations = {
    numericDifference: function(a, b) {
        return Math.abs(a - b);
    },
    numericRatio: function(a, b) {
        if ((a === 0) && (b === 0)) {
            return 0;
        } else if (a * b === 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return (a > 0) ? (b / a) : (a / b);
    }
};

let settingsFunctions = {
    a: "numericDifference",
    b: "numericDifference",
    c: "numericRatio",
};

function getDeviation(settings, preferences) {
   let deviation = 0;
   for (let k in settings) {
       if (settingsFunctions[k]) {
           deviation += customDeviations[settingsFunctions[k]](settings[k], preferences[k]);
       } else if ((!preferences[k]) || (settings[k] !== preferences[k])) {
           deviation++;
       }
   }
   return deviation;
}

let settings = {
    a: 10,
    b: 12,
    c: 15,
    d: 16
};

let preferences = {
    a: 5,
    b: 6,
    c: 8,
    d: 9
};

console.log(getDeviation(settings, preferences));
```

In the above, we have some custom deviation calculating functions and a map to specify which setting should be calculated by what function. For `a` we have numeric difference specified, so it's 5, `b` is also specified to be computed based on numeric difference, so the result for `b` is 6, `c` is specified to be computed based on numeric ratio, resulting in 8/15 and `d` has no custom deviation calculator specified, so it will have a 1 if it's different and 0 if not. So:

- difference for `a`: 5
- difference for `b`: 6
- difference for `c`: 8/15 = 0.533333
- difference for `d`: 1

In total: 12.533333333333333

So this way you can compute a difference for each settings to your user's preferences and choose the setting which differs the least. Feel free to **define** your custom functions instead of mine and use those. My custom functions were defined without knowing what you actually need, so they are likely different from those that you need.

Finally, if you want to choose individual settings from different main setups rather than a full setup, then you can compute the deviation for each individual setting instead of a full settings-collection comparison like we have above.

Comment: In my problem, the a,b,c,d at each layout(in each item of settingMap at your answer),  might have different value and are not similar. How can handle it ?

Comment: @amirtbi my example was arbitrary. Let me edit my answer and add a setting where they are not similar

Comment: @amirtbi take a look at`fifth`, where a, b, c and d are different from each-other. This does not cause any problem to the mechanism. I used similar values for the settings of the former items due to my lazyness to change pasted values. But they can be different, nothing prevents them from being different. If my answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: but at user preferences, user has not chosen the c option, but the result with less deviation contains the c option.  According to your answer, the user sees the options of c in this screen.

Comment: your criteria is finding similarity through checking having same value or not. but it is not enough for finding the closest setting according user preferences. I am looking for the suitable criteria.

Comment: @amirtbi in my answer on the one hand I have given you a simplistic solution for the simplest case. So, it is simplistic indeed. And, on the other hand I told you that you can apply weighing as well as other functions for your different criteria. Here in the comment section you explained that you need to elaborate on that. Which is cool. But you have not provided any information about how your settings work and why the simplistic solution would not be enough for your different settings.

Comment: @amirtbi so the next step is that you describe how your settings work and how would you desire to compute deviation from your specific settings. It's certainly doable, but only if you provide the information that describes what you exactly have and what you exactly want.

Comment: I've modified my question. Better details are provided at the last of question.

Comment: @amirtbi can you provide more details? Your exact needs are still unclear. Can you provide examples of values? I do understand that some scores are involved, but you did not share any details about it. I will add some details to my answer, but I'm very skeptical about my chances of addressing your actual issue.

Comment: The link is provided for data entries sample.

Comment: @amirtbi okay, I see what your inputs are. But I do not see how you want them to be compared. In the meantime I have edited my answer providing you with further details about how you can differentiate between the rules that you have, but it's still unclear what the difference should be between `watchList: 5` or `watchList: 3`. Is it 5 - 3 = 2? Or is it 5 / 3 = 1.66? You really need to explain what you really intend. My edit to my answer has support for custom functionalities to be used, but it was written before I've seen your data. And I still do not know what your intention is with the vals

Comment: I have updated my codes according you answer, but I am looking for more precise method.

Comment: @amirtbi I have invested quite a lot of energy into helping you and I find it unfair that after repeatedly asking you to describe what you exactly need and repeatedly not getting that information from you, you judge my answer as being imprecise. You should be precise in order to have any reason to expect an answer to fulfill your need precisely. I will not invest any more effort into helping you until you provide a proper description of what is the **exact** need you need to fulfill. There is no way around that. If you do not provide me that information, then good luck with your problem.

Comment: Thanks  a lot. I would like to express my gratitude. Sorry if the questions lacks the specification in detail. But your comments helped me a lot to understand what it needs to be solved.

Comment: @amirtbi I really hope for your success and I'm glad the info I have given you was helpful.